# LINQ query getting runtime error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have this linq query and am using EF edmx.

```
        forms = (from f in db.Forms
                 join ffl in db.FormFirstLetters on f.FormID equals ffl.FormID
                 where f.IsActive
                 where criteria.CategoryNames == null || criteria.CategoryNames.Contains(f.Category)
                 where startsWith == null || startsWith.Contains(ffl.FirstLetter)
                 orderby f.FormName
                 select new FormSummary
                 {
                     FormID = f.FormID,
                     Category = f.Category,
                     FormName = f.FormName,
                     AcceptSubmissions = f.AcceptSubmissions,
                     TodaysEntries = f.FormSubmissions.Count(tbl => tbl.SubmissionDate >= todaysDate),
                     TotalEntries = f.FormSubmissions.Count(),
                     LatestEntry = f.FormSubmissions.OrderByDescending(x => x.SubmissionDate).Select(x => x.SubmissionDate).FirstOrDefault()
                 }).ToArray();
```

I am getting this error

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types
>   ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

I thought using `Contains` was acceptable and have used it many times before in these types of linq queries but for some reason it is not working. Both `criteria.CategoryNames` and `startsWith` are `IEnumerable<string>` and the field being searched for are strings. Why is this not working?

Comment: Note: There is no reason to use multiple `where` clauses. Just use `&&` and parantheses.

Answer (score 0):

Had a value in one of the lists that was an empty string. Apparently EF doesn't know how to translate that to sql? Wow.